# Preventing duplicate numbers and asking for user to reenter

Tags: c#, arrays

Everything I have runs fine, but I am looking for a way to prompt the user if duplicate order number is entered and have them reenter a new order number. Right now it just accepts duplicates and does not display the error message I wanted. I created two classes `Order` the base, and `ShippedOrder`. Here is the equals method I have within the `Order` class.

```
    public override bool Equals(Object e)
    {
        bool equal;
        Order temp = (Order)e;
        if (orderNumber == temp.orderNumber)
            equal = true;
        else
            equal = false;
        return equal;
```

Here is what I have within the main method. I can post everything if it would help. Again I am looking for help finding a way to prevent the user form imputing the same two order numbers.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        double sum = 0;
        ShippedOrder[] orderArray = new ShippedOrder[5];
        ShippedOrder[] check = new ShippedOrder[5];
        bool wrong = true;
        for (int x = 0; x < orderArray.Length; ++x)
        {

            orderArray[x] = new ShippedOrder();

            Console.Write("Enter order number: ");
            orderArray[x].orderNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int y = 0; y < x; ++y)
            {
                check[y] = new ShippedOrder();
                if (orderArray[x].Equals(check[y]))
                    wrong = false;
                    while (!wrong)
                    {
  Console.WriteLine("Sorry, the order number {0} is a duplicate. \nPlease reenter {1}", 
  orderArray[x], check[y]);
                        for (y = 0; y < x; ++y)
                        {
                        if (orderArray[x].Equals(check[y]))
                            wrong = false;
                        }
                        check[y] = orderArray[x];
                    }
            }


            Console.Write("Enter cusomer name: ");
            orderArray[x].customerName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Enter quanity: ");
            orderArray[x].quanityOrdered = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Inside your second `for` loop you are giving check[y] a new ShippedOrder object which presumably doesn't have an ID. When you compare it to `x` there is no match.

Comment: Easiest way would be to change your orderarray from a ShippedOrder[] type to a List<ShippedOrder> type. Then you can use orderarray.Contains(ShippedOrder newOrder) inside an input loop.

Comment: I agree the problem is check[y] has no value I just do not know how to give it a value without making it equal to orderArray[x] which just causes an infinate loop, or seemingly equal to zero. I need to find a way to make check[y] equal all the previous user inputs. Also I am not too familiar with the List<ShippedOrder> type. We have not gone over this yet in class. I think this is how my professor wants it done so I was hoping to use this way to reach the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with LINQ, this is where it actually shines (if this code is not called thousand times per second)

```
var arrayExpectedCount = 5;
var orderArray = new List<ShippedOrder>(); //define array of orders to generate
var check = new List<ShippedOrder>();      //array of orders already shipped,already present
...... 
//infinit interation
while(true) {
   var orderNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
   if(!check.Exist(o=>o.orderNumber == orderNumber)
   {
      //create a new order and push it to the orderArray 
   }

   //break condition of the infinit loop
   if(orderArray.Count == arrayExpectedCount)
       break;

}
```

If this is not what you're asking for, please clarify.

Comment: I think [List(T).Exist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bfed8bca.aspx) isn't _strictly_ Linq, the Linq (and IEnumerable(T) therefore) equivalent is [Linq.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx), but I believe they provide identical behavior for Lists, and the Answer still stands. Felt it was worth saying in-case the OP or others use something other than a Generic List in their implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<ShippedOrder> orderArray = new List<ShippedOrder>();
do {
    int newOrderNum = 0;
    // Retrieve first attempt
    Console.Write("Enter order number: ");
    newOrderNUm = Conver.ToInt32(ConsoleReadLine());
    // Check if any of the orders in orderArray have the same order number
    while(orderArray.Any(a=>a.orderNumber == newOrderNum) {
        Console.Write("Sorry, the order number is a duplicate. Please enter re-enter the order number: ");
        newOrderNum = Conver.ToInt32(ConsoleReadLine());
    };
    orderArray.Add(new ShippedOrder() {
        orderNumber = newOrderNum,
    };
} while(orderArray.Length < 5);
```